# Is this code correct to add a background image using css?

Tags: html, css

```
body{
background:url("?../img/by.jpg") no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
```

}

Will this code work in all browsers
Or I can do it without the question mark???

Comment: Is `../img/by.jpg` a part of query string?

Comment: have you tried it on the browser?

Comment: Yes but it was not showing

Comment: I don't understand why you have a query string not a full(er) url. What image is the browser supposed to be picking up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and it will work on all the browsers.

```css
body{
/*
background: color-name url("image-source") repeat-property attachment-property position-property;
Shorthand Example :- */
background: #D0E4F5 url("https://picsum.photos/200") no-repeat scroll 0px 0px;
/*
Long Example :-
#demo {
background-color: #D0E4F5;
background-image: url("/images/smiley.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 0px 0px;
}
*/

}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
Some Example Text
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code snipet here isnt really usefull since its an example image and the image will not show. and also he is just asking *Will this code work in all browsers?* so those shorthand and longhand examples arent needed. And also consider adding more explanation to the answer to help us understand more instead of just posting a block of code and say "try this haha it will magically work".

Answer (score 0):

Use this to background image to an element also this will work in all browsers

```css
element {
  background-image: url('your_Source');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: What part of your answer makes it the best? What are other ways?

Comment: This will not work on all browsers as you state. The background-attachment will make it fuzzy on Safari IOS (see caniuse.com).